# Dropdown List Selection Value Disable

Tags: php, mysql

because i really don't have idea how can i going to have a solution on this problem. But it is posible to disable a value in dropdown list after it has been selected? and go to the next value? if its posible how? any help will be much appreciated thank you. btw the data in database are in dropdownlist im using mysql

```
     <div id="container">
  <table width="420" align="center">
 <form name="fmNames" id="fmNames" method="post" action="vote.php" 
onSubmit="return positionValidate(this)">
 <tr>
<td>Choose Position</td>
<td><SELECT NAME="position" id="position" onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="select">select
<?php 
//loop through all table rows
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 
//mysql_free_result($positions_retrieved);
//mysql_close($link);
}
?>
</SELECT></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="See Candidates" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td> 
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    </form> 
  </table>
 <table width="500" align="center">
   <form>
 <tr>

      <th>Grade</th>
<th></th>
<th>Section</th>
  </tr>
   <?php
    //loop through all table rows
  //if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
      if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
      {
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row['candidate_gender']."</td";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['candidate_grade']."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row['candidate_section']."</td";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
                  Print '<td><img src="date:image/jpeg;base64,' .base64_encode($row['image']).'"height="60 width="75 /></td>';

   echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['hello']."</td>";

  echo "<td><input type='radio' name='vote' value='$row[candidate_name]' onclick='getVote(this.value)' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     }

 mysql_free_result($result); 
   mysql_close($link);
  //}
      }
  else
 // do nothing
     ?>



     <?php
   // retrieving positions sql query
   $positions=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbPositions")
  or die("There are no records to display ... \n" . 

    mysql_error()); 
?>
<?php
     // retrieval sql query
  // check if Submit is set in POST
      if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
      {
        // get position value
    $position = ( $_POST['position'] ); //prevents types of SQL injection


     // retrieve based on position
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbCandidates WHERE 
  candidate_position='$position'")
  or die(" There are no records at the moment ... \n"); 

  // redirect back to vote
    //header("Location: vote.php");
    }
   else
  // do something

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all the options of your dropdown with js.
Then iterate over them, check if one is currently selected and if so, remove it and set the next one to selected.

I don't see a way to do this without using javascript tho.

Edit: Here is my sample code:

my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="position">
        <option value="pos1">pos1</option>
        <option value="pos2">pos2</option>
        <option value="pos3">pos3</option>
        <option value="pos4">pos4</option>
        <option value="pos5">pos5</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

my app.js:

```
function disableOption(name){
    // get the select
    var pos = document.querySelector('#position');

    // remove the option
    var lastActive = pos.selectedIndex;
    pos.remove(pos.selectedIndex);

    // set next one as active (check here if lastActive < pos.length and what to do if not)
        pos.options[lastActive].selected = true;
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('#position').addEventListener('change', disableOption);
}
```

I appended my function to the change event of the SELECT so it remove the selected option right after you click on it and sets the next one as selected.
Example: if you click on pos3 it will be removed and pos4 will be selected.

I hope that was how you wanted it to work.